# How can I run a stored procedure with begin and end in an JdbcBatchItemWriter in a spring batch program?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, spring-batch

I have a spring batch program and I would like to set the sql as a stored procedure.

```sql
BEGIN INSERT INTO D_MED_LIMIT_OVERRIDE(SRC_ENV_SK) VALUES(:srcEnvSk) EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN NULL END
```

When I use this I get the error:

```
Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
;
```

Not sure if this can be done. But does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not properly terminating the statements *inside* the anonymous block:

```
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO D_MED_LIMIT_OVERRIDE(SRC_ENV_SK) 
   VALUES(:srcEnvSk); --<< here
EXCEPTION 
   WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN NULL; --<< here
END
```

When sending statement to an Oracle server the complete statement must not be terminated with a `;` though. That's why no `;` is required after the `END`